# How to fix require missing parameter error in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I started a project in PhpStorm. It's a Laravel project and I already installed the Laravel plugin and ide-helper, but still getting this weird errors:

[image: Required Parameter is missing]

And the others are expecting statement errors. Anyone know how to fix them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not Laravel user .. so have to ask this possibly dumb question -- is that code actually correct/working and it's PhpStorm who is wrongly complaining? if so -- `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper ? It can generate a code file that phpstorm parses for method signatures.

Comment: The code is working. It's the starter skeleton, which is coming with laravel. So it's more a PHPStorm / Settings problem.

Comment: @simon-svensson Yep, I installed and enabled the laravel phpstorm plugin and installed the ide-helper via composer. And the ide helper is working, I have autocompletion for the laravel methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- should help with such kind of errors (usually does).

---

If the above does not help -- disable all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins and see if made any difference. If did -- enable one by one until you find the problematic one.

Comment: Tried it. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Maybe it's not a PHP file then (as seen by IDE, of course)? Because it should help with such errors. Also -- 1) Your OS; 2) IDE version exactly; 3) Sounds stupid .. but was IDE actually restarted?

Comment: 1) OSX 10.10.3
2)  PHPStorm 8.0.3
3) Yep, several times. :/

Comment: Well .. lets try again with this: 1) Disable all 3rd party (not bundled, even Laravel one) plugins and close IDE -- that's in case if one of the plugins is messing around; 2) Navigate to `~/Library/Caches/WebIde80` [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and delete whole folder; 3) Launch IDE -- see if it made any difference (especially about commas etc). 4) If still exactly the same -- share your idea.log somewhere (whole file plz) -- `Help | Show Log in...` 5) What icon such files do have?

Comment: Ha, okay I found the problem. I was using seti ui theme for phpstorm and it was a problem with the php icons, which replace the normal php.jar.